# Cassandra Select issue after altering column from int to varint

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there something special about varints in Cassandra? I have a table with varint columns, and the following select statement is not working:

```
select * from hourly_average where application_id = 3 and partner_id = 1 and location_id = 1 and device_id = 10003;
```

application_id, partner_id and location_id are varints. If I convert them to be regular ints, then the select statement works fine. When they are varints, it returns 0 results, even though there are lots of results that match those values.

UPDATE: Added table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.hourly_average (
    application_id varint,
    partner_id varint,
    location_id varint,
    device_id int,
    day date,
    hour int,
    average float,
    count int,
    max float,
    min float,
    PRIMARY KEY ((application_id, partner_id, location_id, device_id), day, hour)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (day DESC, hour DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Some output from select *

```
 application_id | partner_id | location_id | device_id | day        | hour | average    | count | max  | min
----------------+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------+------------+-------+------+------
              3 |          1 |           1 |     20004 | 2016-12-01 |    2 |          0 |     1 |    0 |    0
              3 |          1 |           1 |     20004 | 2016-12-01 |    1 |          0 |     2 |    0 |    0
              3 |          1 |           1 |     20004 | 2016-12-01 |    0 |          0 |     2 |    0 |    0
              3 |          1 |           1 |     20004 | 2016-11-30 |   23 |          0 |     2 |    0 |    0
              3 |          1 |           1 |     10003 | 2016-12-01 |    2 | 1290.80017 |    75 | 1553 |  820
              3 |          1 |           1 |     10003 | 2016-12-01 |    1 |  888.19165 |   120 |  957 |  830
              3 |          1 |           1 |     10003 | 2016-12-01 |    0 |  991.09167 |   120 | 1062 |  896
```

The version is dsc-cassandra 3.0.9.

NOTE:

It does seem to be related to the column originally being an int, and me altering the table and making it a varint. If I create a brand new table with just a single column of type int, add some data, and then alter it to be of type varint, the same issue occurs. Is there some sort of bug with changing column type form int to varint?

Comment: Can you post your table definition?  Are you using any secondary indexes?  And which version are you on?  Very strange indeed...I just tried your example and it worked fine, so I'll need to see exactly what your table looks like.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: Note, it does seem to be related to the column originally being an int, and me altering the table and making it a varint. If I create a brand new table with just a single column of type int, add some data, and then alter it to be of type varint, the same issue occurs. Is there some sort of bug with changing column type form int to varint?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem although I don't think we changed the column type from int to varint - it was varint from the beginning.

The only thing that worked for me was double conversion hack:

```
(...) where key = blobAsVarint(intAsBlob(1))
```